# How to test htmlpurifier using php?

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

First i download [htmlpurifier-4.8.0](http://htmlpurifier.org/releases/htmlpurifier-4.8.0.zip). Then uploaded it to my hosting, this is the code without `htmlpurifier`:

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    include("connect.php");
    $dirty_html = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_mysqli,$_POST['xx']);
    echo $dirty_html;
}
?>

<form method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data">
<input name="xx" type="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

In the input `name="xx"` I fill in data `<script>alert("test");</script>777`, and gotten echo `777`.

And here's the code with `htmlpurifier` usage:

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    include("connect.php");
    require_once 'htmlpurifier-4.8.0/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php'; 
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
    $dirty_html = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_mysqli,$_POST['xx']);
    $clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
    echo $clean_html;
}
?>
<form method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data">
<input name="xx" type="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

I repeat the same test with the input. Can someone explain the difference, why `without htmlpurifier` and `with htmlpurifier` I'm getting the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $dirty_html = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_mysqli,$_POST['xx']);
 // $dirty_html  has 777 value now 
  $clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
 // $clean_html has 777 value because there is nothing to
   purify in 777 which is a valid value
```

`mysqli_real_escape_string` already converts the input to 777.

Comment: It's mean i can not use `mysqli_real_escape_string` with `htmlpurifier` ?

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string already cleans the string, htmlpurifier basically cleans string (removes html tags etc).

Comment: you must not pass params in the queries. Use PDO and have the binding mechanism of parameters..

Comment: So i have to select one from  htmlpurifier or mysqli_real_escape_string ?

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string  is what musql provides, it is better to use both on the safe side since I am not sure which values can't be cleaned by `mysqli_real_escape_string` or by htmlpurifier .

Comment: bind the params, you won't have to worry about sql injection them..
sample code I wrote sometime ago

`$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$mysql_dbname.';host='.$mysql_servername, $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
$stmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT ID, fromName, fromEmail, toName, toEmail, date, subject, body FROM messages WHERE  ID = ?;");
$stmt->execute(array($messageid));
$data=  $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Then i use `htmlpurifier` before and then use `mysqli_real_escape_string` it's ok ?

Comment: upvote or marked it as answered if that solved your problem